# Why particles.js height not expanding?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, particles.js

I want to use **particles.js** for my project background. I'm having an issue with height. It's not expanding height in device web. Actually height property is not working. Please help me with this.

**Here is the code:**

> https://codesandbox.io/s/4zv0329nn0

[image]

**particle.js component.**

```
import React from "react";
import Particles from "react-particles-js";

export default () => (
  <div
    style={{
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      backgroundColor: "blue"
    }}
  >
    <Particles
      params={{
        particles: {
          number: {
            value: 50
          },
          size: {
            value: 3
          }
        },
        interactivity: {
          events: {
            onhover: {
              enable: true,
              mode: "repulse"
            }
          }
        }
      }}
    />
  </div>
);
```

**App component.**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        margin: "0",
        padding: "0"
      }}
    >
      <ParticleComponent />
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%"
        }}
      >
        <h1>test</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: do you need like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1aupup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `height={window.outerHeight}` `prop` to `ParticleComponent`.

Solution here

[image: Edit 0oqy1mn04n]